# Marshal wchar_t*** from C++ to C# as an out parameter?

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I have these functions inside a dll:

```
DWORD getTypes(const char* const i_formName, const char* const i_fieldName, wchar_t*** i_output, int* i_size)
{
    try
    {
        std::vector<std::wstring> i_temp;
        multilanguage.getTypes(i_formName, i_fieldName, i_temp);
        *i_size = i_temp.size();
        *i_output = new wchar_t *[*i_size];
        for (int i = 0; i < *i_size; ++i)
        {
            *i_output[i] = new wchar_t[i_temp[i].length() + 1];
            wcscpy_s(*i_output[i], i_temp[i].length() + 1, i_temp[i].c_str());
        }

        return 0;
    }
    catch (MultilanguageException & e)
    {
        return e.getErr();
    }
}

void FreeString(wchar_t ** i_output)
{
    if (NULL != (*i_output))
        delete[](*i_output);
}
```

These functions work because if I use them inside a C++ program, I get the expected results.

Unfortunately I need to call these functions from a C# program. I wrapped the functions in the following way:

```
[DllImport("multilanguage_c.dll", EntryPoint = "getTypes", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern UInt32 _getTypes([In] string i_formName, 
                                       [In] string i_fieldName, 
                                       out IntPtr i_output, ref int size);

[DllImport("multilanguage_c.dll", EntryPoint = "FreeString", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void _FreeString(ref IntPtr i_output);

static public string[] getTypes(string i_formName, string i_fieldName)
{
    IntPtr i_result = IntPtr.Zero;
    int size = 0;
    IntPtr stringSize = IntPtr.Zero;
    UInt32 err = _getTypes(i_formName, i_fieldName, out i_result, ref size);
    if (0 != err)
    {
        ExceptionHandler.ExcpetionThrower(err);
    }
    string[] ManagedStrArray = null;
    MarshalUnmananagedStrArray2ManagedStrArray(i_result, size, out ManagedStrArray);
    return ManagedStrArray;
}

static private void MarshalUnmananagedStrArray2ManagedStrArray(IntPtr pUnmanagedStringArray, // Pointer to an array of unmanaged WCHAR pointers.
                                                               int StringCount,  // The total number of WCHAR*s in pUnmanagedStringArray.
                                                               out string[] ManagedStringArray  // Receipient of the array of managed strings.
                                                               )
{
        // First allocate an array of IntPtrs.
        IntPtr[] pIntPtrArray = new IntPtr[StringCount];
        // Also allocate an array of managed strings using
        // the ManagedStringArray parameter.
        ManagedStringArray = new string[StringCount];

        // Copy the WCHAR*s from pUnmanagedStringArray to 
        // the array of IntPtrs (pIntPtrArray).
        Marshal.Copy(pUnmanagedStringArray, pIntPtrArray, 0, StringCount);

        // Then, one by one, convert each of the WCHAR*s 
        // inside the pIntPtrArray array into a managed string.
        for (int i = 0; i < StringCount; i++)
        {
            ManagedStringArray[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(pIntPtrArray[i]);
            _FreeString(ref pIntPtrArray[i]);
        }

        // Finally, free the entire buffer of unmanaged
        // WCHAR*s.
        _FreeString(ref pUnmanagedStringArray);
}
```

In the function `MarshalUnmananagedStrArray2ManagedStrArray` if `StringCount` is greater then 1, at the second attempt of `ManagedStringArray[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(pIntPtrArray[i]);` I get the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

I tried also to comment the line `_FreeString(ref pIntPtrArray[i]);` thought the `_FreeString` function did something wrong but nothing has changed. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Pretty sure this has nothing to do with C

Comment: Not seen a [3 star](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) programmer in quite some time.

Comment: I need a 3 star variable because I don't know *a priori* how many `char*` I have to instantiate. Furthermore to be able to call the function using `p/invoke` I had to define the function as `extern C` to avoid the name mangling and thus I can't use anything than pointers.